# Wso2 Multi factor authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are currently have 2.6.0 wso2 api manager and we hace a requirements to add multi factor authentication for our wso2 api manager.I have got the steps to add multi factor authentication for wso2 identity server from the official documentstion(given link below).Can u clarify if the steps are same for both identity server and api manager. Can u also clarify whether we can implement this steps in 2.6.0 version wso2 api manager.

I have referred the below link for enabling MFA

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-sms-otp/

Answer (score 0):

As out-of-the-box, the WSO2 API Manager doesn't support full-fledged Identity capabilities. Therefore, if you want to secure your Portals with MFA, it is recommended to configure an Identity Server as Key Manager with WSO2 API Manager.

Follow [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager) to configure WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager with WSO2 API Manager v2.6.0.